# Why do we need 'private' methods in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Can someone give me a concrete example where a 'private' method would accomplish something that can't be done with a 'protected' method? In other words I am want to know why a language designer would put 'private' methods in Ruby.

Comment: you're right that they don't enable any more functionality than protected or public. Actually, they take away functionality - specifically, they make the method slightly more difficult to run outside of the class / module they're defined in. Consider a helper method which is used internally by another method. Somebody using the library will probably not be calling this helper method directly. It could be marked as private so somebody browsing the source code recognizes this functionality. It's like typechecking in that it doesn't add functionality, but may make developers lives easier.

Comment: one use of private methods I have found is their use in defining 'global' methods (methods defined outside of any class) these methods become private methods of Object and can be called without any receiver, thus mimicking a more non-object oriented style. However this is more of a 'syntactic sugar' feature than a language design issue.

Comment: I don't really understand. If you're defining a global method i.e. `def foo` at the global scope. what difference does it make if its public or private? In either case, you'd be able to just call `foo`. It's also worth mentioning that private or protected never completely prevents calling the method - it just requires `send` to be used sometimes.

Comment: @maxpleaner: Making "global procedures" `private` methods means that they can *only* be called with *no* receiver. This helps re-inforce their procedural nature. You can't confuse people by calling `'Hello'.puts` and leave them wondering why this doesn't print "Hello". It will be a `NoMethodError`, you can only call `puts 'Hello'`. (Or `some_io_stream.puts`, assuming that `some_io_stream` contains an `IO` object.) "Global procedures" ignore their receiver, they don't do anything with `self`, so it helps making them `private` and forcing the programmer to leave out the (useless) receiver.

Comment: Thanks @JörgWMittag I never realized that one could call global methods with a receiver anyway.

Comment: @maxpleaner: They *aren't* "global methods". There is no such thing in Ruby. Every method is an instance method, there is no other kind of method. "Global methods" are actually instance methods of `Object`, and since everything is an `Object`, you could theoretically call "global methods" on any object … except you can't, because they become `private` instance methods of `Object`. (Arguably, they should rather become instance methods of `Kernel`, but that is a whole new discussion.)

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on your development team and how your code is going to be used. In Ruby these tags are often suggestions more than hard and fast rules, there's ways to bypass `private` and `protected` methods if necessary, but they can serve as a strong hint to someone using your code that calling them is undesirable.

`private` is something that should be used sparingly as it can make life very difficult for those trying to subclass something. `protected` is usually sufficient, and helps steer external code to the methods that *should* be used.

There are occasions where `private` is necessary, that is you want to prevent subclasses from knowing too much about how the parent class works. This is more common in libraries where you encourage people to subclass but you also want to wall off some of the internal functions that aren't intended to be used by them. This allows you to refactor these methods later at will without breaking someone else's code.

One of the principles of good object-oriented design is controlling how much method exposure you have. Too much exposure means you're committed to making them behave identically now and in the future unless you're prepared to make breaking changes. Too little exposure means your class might be difficult to use, if not useless. Finding that balance is always tricky.

So `private` and `protected` exist for reasons, and it's largely the same reasons that C++, Java, PHP, Python and many others have these. It's to assert control over how and where your methods should be used.

Comment: Can you give an example where `private` makes it hard to subclass?

Comment: @JörgWMittag If you're overly protective about your methods and your subclass needs access to one of these `private` methods in order to do anything useful, then that's when it's an issue. It's highly situational, but you'll know when it happens because the very thing you need is locked behind glass.

Comment: I don't see how a superclass can prevent access to a method to a subclass by making it `private`. Can you give an example where `private` prevents access to a method of a superclass in a subclass?

Comment: To be more precise: I cannot envision a scenario where preventing access to some `private` method in the subclass would not also prevent access to the same method in the superclass. I.e. if `foo` is `private`, then I can *always* call `foo` regardless of whether I am in the superclass or the subclass, and I can *never* call `bar.foo`, again, regardless of whether I am in the superclass or the subclass. In other words: inheritance is completely irrelevant.

Comment: Yeah, that is odd. After [reading up more on this quirky thing](http://lylejohnson.name/blog/2003/12/09/private-methods-in-c-and-ruby/) it seems like the difference is a lot harder to pin down. I'm used to the differentiation being more strongly enforced in other languages and have never really found a use case for `private` in Ruby per-se.